# adding up count values of unique sequences in a txt file

Tags: python

In 2 .txt files, I have 2 columns each having similar sequences with the second column in each file being count 
 part of the file,

```
    NNNNCGGTTGNGGTATGG      1
    NANNTGTGACCATGAATG      1
    NGNNTGAGTCGTACGTTT      1
    GTACACTGTCCAACGCTG      1
    ACCCTCCCGCGTGCGCTG      1
    TGNNNACAGNCANAACCC      8
    TGNNNACAGNCANAACCA      3
    GNNNGNGGGGGCGNGNGT      1
    NNNCGACTAAACNCGTTG      1
    TGNNNACAGNCANAACCC      8
```

I want to add up the count values for each time the sequence occurs. 
for example, “NNNNCGGTTGNGGTATGG” appears 3 times each with count 1 so the total read count for that sequence read would be 3. 
I finally hope to retrieve read count for each sequence. (Hope panda is not required for this)

Comment: Step one: Read the file line by line. Step two: Split each line into its two columns for further processing. This should get you started, but as a general advise, try to write pseudo-code, i.e. human language, describing the algorithm and only then write the Python code.

Comment: Do you have sample code written ? if yes, share that. @UlrichEckhardt has already mentioned pseudo code.

Comment: `pandas` is not needed to do this. A normal for loop with split and dictionary is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Python provides a datatype for this: [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects).

Comment: The link goes to the documentation for old Python 2, not current Python 3.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Yes it does. The question was tagged "python" indicating that it is non-version specific, and Python 2 is still in widespread use. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) is the Python 3 version.

Answer (score 1):

Use Python's [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) for doing this as follows, where `data1.txt` and `data2.txt` are your two input sources:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()

for filename in ['data1.txt', 'data2.txt']:
    with open(filename) as f_input:
        for line in f_input:
            data, count = line.split()
            counts[data] += int(count)

for data, count in counts.items():
    print(data, count)
```

This would display the following:

```
NGNNTGAGTCGTACGTTT 1
NNNCGACTAAACNCGTTG 1
TGNNNACAGNCANAACCC 16
GNNNGNGGGGGCGNGNGT 1
TGNNNACAGNCANAACCA 3
NNNNCGGTTGNGGTATGG 1
ACCCTCCCGCGTGCGCTG 1
GTACACTGTCCAACGCTG 1
NANNTGTGACCATGAATG 1
```

Comment: this also can be done using normal dictionary using `setdefault` method or using `default dict`. I feel that counter is not actually needed to do this ?.

Comment: You might want to upgrade your answer to modern Python, the link and the code are still using old Python 2. That said, do you really want to do others' homework like that?